# C# How get bitmap from dynamic <img> in code behind in .aspx

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, code-behind

I'm using a video tag to capture a screenshot of the video in a web page and put it into an img element. Then I want to post it to the code behind so I can process its bitmap.  I'm using an UpdatePanel for the postback.  When I run this in a debugger, it captures the image from the video, builds the canvas, draws the image into the  element, displays the image correctly, and then calls the Decode function in the code behind.  However, the img.src is blank in the code behind Decode function.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" EnablePartialRendering="true"/>
<asp:Button runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnClientClick="return screenshotButton()" OnClick="Decode" Text="Capture"></asp:Button>
<canvas id="theCanvas" style="display: none;"></canvas>
<img runat="server" Name="theImg" Id="theImg"/>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

...

```
function screenshotButton() {
    canvas.width = videoElement.videoWidth;
    canvas.height = videoElement.videoHeight;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(videoElement, 0, 0);
    theImg.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp');
    return true;
};
```

How can I get a bitmap of theImg in the code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of an image doesn't get included in the postback data.

Since you are using an `UpdatePanel`, you could add a `HiddenField` into which you also store the Base64 Data URI.
On postback, you can read and parse the content of this hidden field.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" value=""  />
```

Include this in your script.

```
document.getElementById("HiddenField").value = canvas.toDataURL('image/webp');
```

Comment: That was almost awesome!  Only problem is I guess I don't know how to parse it correctly.  I took off the data:image/webp;base64, from the front of the string, and used Convert.FromBase64String to convert it to a byte array.  But when I saved it as a png and tried to open it, it said invalid format.

Comment: I use `canvas.toDataURL()` without arguments, which should result in a `.png` like eg. `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...` of which you pass the last part behind the comma to `Convert.FromBase64String`. Store the resulting bytes in a `MemoryStream` and call `Image.FromStream`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it by using asp:Image
Then you can set the source programmatically.